# Laravel 7.3 does not appear to install Vue, the components folder and ExampleComponent.vue are missing

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Laravel is said to come with a Vue installation already packaged, but this no longer appears to be the case. Laravel 7.3 doesn't have the components folder and ExampleComponent.vue are missing.

I would like to get Vue running on Laravel.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you put some important codes(installation/configuration) because we want to know **(1)** If you already installed the vue inside the **package.json** **(2)** Did you configured/setup the vue inside your **app.js** correctly? **(3)** Did you put the `<script src="/app.js></script>` inside your view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The frontend scaffolding typically provided with previous releases of Laravel has been extracted into a `laravel/ui` Composer package. This allows the first-party UI scaffolding to be developed and versioned separately from the primary framework. As a result of this change, no `Bootstrap` or `Vue` code is present in default framework scaffolding, and the `make:auth` command has been extracted from the framework as well.

https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/releases#laravel-6

Inorder to generate the Presets read the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/frontend

Comment: Running these commands installed Vue into Laravel: `composer require laravel/ui`  `php artisan ui vue`  `npm install && npm run dev`   Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Bootstrap and Vue scaffolding provided by Laravel is located in the laravel/ui Composer package, which may be installed using Composer:

```
composer require laravel/ui
```

Once the laravel/ui package has been installed, you may install the frontend scaffolding using the ui Artisan command:

```
// Generate basic scaffolding...
php artisan ui bootstrap
php artisan ui vue
php artisan ui react // use this if you need react instead of vue

// Generate login / registration scaffolding...
php artisan ui bootstrap --auth
php artisan ui vue --auth
php artisan ui react --auth
```

Once done with the `vue artisan` command, you can find the `ExampleComponent.vue` and the basic files in the `js` folder.

[Reference](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/frontend)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get Vue working on Laravel using this as the correct example:

`https://github.com/connor11528/laravel-vue-spa-tailwindcss`